# On Access Token Expiry - JWT Authentication - DocuSign

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Referencing video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebwN2HWpDQA

Environment: Node.js

In the video they show how to get an `access_token` using the JWT. Documentation says the lifetime of the `access_token` can only be 1 hour so what do we do once the token expires? Can we simply use the JWT again with an updated date-time in UNIX epoch format for the `iat` and `exp` values to get a new `access_token`?

If I do update the `iat` and `exp` I get the following error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "no_valid_keys_or_signatures"
}
```

How should we get a new access token?

Answer (score 0):

When an access token expires, you will need to generate a new JWT assertion, sign it, and use it to request a new access token.

Reusing the old assertion with modified IAT and EXP values won't work without also generating a new signature using your RSA Private Key.

Comment: Can you please shed some light on how you actually *"generate a new signature using your RSA private key"*?

Comment: Step two's "Signature" section here: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/ - That said we generally recommend using a library to handle the JWT exchange instead of generating it manually.